# Orbit Deep Linking Foundation 6

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5, zurb-foundation-6

I want to change images in orbit with buttons instead of bullets. It was called "deep linking" in Foundation 5.
Here it is:
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/orbit.html

How can I do the same in Foundation 6?

Comment: Did the buttons work for you?

Comment: Nope. I switched to tabs. http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tabs.html

Answer (score 0):

In your `<ul class="orbit-container">` and as a sibling to your slides (`<li class="orbit-slide">`),  place the buttons:

```
<button class="orbit-previous" aria-label="previous">
    <span class="show-for-sr">Previous Slide</span>
    &#9664;
</button>

<button class="orbit-next" aria-label="next">
    <span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span>
    &#9654;
</button>
```

Those buttons are as shown on the [Foundation 6 Orbit doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/orbit.html#basics)